# Terminate Runnable when instantiator has been terminated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-handler

I have many fragments/components that are placed on the screen, not all of them are displayed at the same time, some of them are being replaced/removed from time to time.

I've created a refresh mechanism a fragment can implement in order to keep it's data up to date.

```
public class RefreshSingleton {
    List<Runnable> tasks;
    Handler handler;

    private static RefreshSingleton instance = null;

    public static RefreshManager getInstance() {
        ...
    }

    public Runnable register(int offset, final int interval,final RefresTask task) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.onRefresh();
                handler.postDelayed(this,interval);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,offset);
        tasks.add(runnable);
        return runnable;
    }
}
```

I'm using handlers because the refresh involves UI changes, I'm looking for a way for a Runnable to find out if it's parent fragment is no longer on the screen and stop iterating.

Do you have any suggestion on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. Why can't you just stop the runnable in onPause() (but I think onPause() is tightly coupled with the activity so maybe in OnDestroyView()) of the fragment's lifecycle?

Comment: @JuanAcevedo that is an option I'm considering, the component I'm updating is not guaranteed to be Activity/Fragment and to have a onDestroy() type of function.

Comment: If its not guaranteed to have an onDestroy() type function, then create one using a callback. The callback gets called whenever the fragment's onDestroyView() is called. I'm assuming the component is coupled with the fragment since it depends on it being no longer on screen to stop iterating. But then again, if it is coupled with the fragment, you don't need a callback and you can just call it whenver onDestroyView is called.